# Why does running a second viewpropertyanimation on a view break the animation listeners?

Tags: android, android-animation, viewpropertyanimator

I have a strange issue where my onAnimationEnd gets called repeatedly (hence my animation keeps running over and over even though I'm not explicitly calling it).

Here is a screen recording of what's happening: https://youtu.be/TfGiLvwLdBM

The following is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "TT_MainActivity";

ActivityMainBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    setupViews();
    showLogin();
}

private void setupViews() {
    // Login views
    binding.loginContainer.setTranslationY(Utils.getScreenHeight(this));
    binding.tvNotRegistered.setTranslationY(Utils.getScreenHeight(this));
    binding.tvLoginTitle.setTranslationY(-Utils.dpToPx(500));
    binding.etEmail.setTranslationY(-Utils.dpToPx(500));
    binding.etPassword.setTranslationY(-Utils.dpToPx(500));
    binding.btnLogin.setTranslationY(-Utils.dpToPx(500));

    // Signup views
    binding.signupContainer.setTranslationY(-Utils.getScreenHeight(this));
    binding.tvAlreadyHaveAAccount.setTranslationY(-Utils.getScreenHeight(this));
    binding.tvSignupTitle.setTranslationY(-Utils.dpToPx(500));
    binding.etEmailSignup.setTranslationY(-Utils.dpToPx(500));
    binding.etPasswordSignup.setTranslationY(-Utils.dpToPx(500));
    binding.btnSignup.setTranslationY(-Utils.dpToPx(500));

    // Click listeners
    setOnClickListeners();
}

private void setOnClickListeners() {
    // LOGIN
    binding.btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "login()...");
        }
    });

    binding.tvNotRegistered.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "showSignup()..");
            binding.tvNotRegistered.animate()
                    .translationY(Utils.getScreenHeight(MainActivity.this))
                    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            binding.loginContainer.animate()
                    .translationY(Utils.getScreenHeight(MainActivity.this))
                    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
                    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationEnd: showSignup()");
                            binding.loginContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            binding.tvNotRegistered.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            showSignup();
                        }
                    });
        }
    });

    binding.btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "signup()...");
        }
    });

    // SIGNUP
    binding.tvAlreadyHaveAAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "showLogin()..");
            binding.tvAlreadyHaveAAccount.animate()
                    .translationY(-Utils.getScreenHeight(MainActivity.this))
                    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            binding.signupContainer.animate()
                    .translationY(-Utils.getScreenHeight(MainActivity.this))
                    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
                    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationEnd: showLogin()");
                            binding.signupContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            binding.tvAlreadyHaveAAccount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            showLogin();
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}


// SIGNUP
private void showSignup() {
    binding.signupContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    binding.tvAlreadyHaveAAccount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    binding.signupContainer.animate()
            .setDuration(300)
            .setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(1.0f))
            .translationY(0)
            .setStartDelay(300);
    binding.tvAlreadyHaveAAccount.animate()
            .setDuration(300)
            .setStartDelay(400)
            .translationY(0)
            .setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(1.0f))
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    animateSignupContainerContents();
                }
            });
}

private void animateSignupContainerContents() {
    binding.tvSignupTitle.animate()
            .translationY(0)
            .setDuration(400)
            .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

    binding.etEmailSignup.animate()
            .translationY(0)
            .setDuration(300)
            .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

    binding.etPasswordSignup.animate()
            .translationY(0)
            .setDuration(200)
            .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

    binding.btnSignup.animate()
            .translationY(0)
            .setDuration(100)
            .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
}

// LOGIN
private void showLogin() {
    binding.loginContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    binding.tvNotRegistered.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    binding.loginContainer.animate()
            .setDuration(300)
            .setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(1.0f))
            .translationY(0)
            .setStartDelay(300);
    binding.tvNotRegistered.animate()
            .setDuration(300)
            .setStartDelay(400)
            .translationY(0)
            .setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(1.0f))
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    animateLoginContainerContents();
                }
            });
}

private void animateLoginContainerContents() {
    binding.tvLoginTitle.animate()
            .translationY(0)
            .setDuration(400)
            .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

    binding.etEmail.animate()
            .translationY(0)
            .setDuration(300)
            .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

    binding.etPassword.animate()
            .translationY(0)
            .setDuration(200)
            .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

    binding.btnLogin.animate()
            .translationY(0)
            .setDuration(100)
            .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
}

}
```

With the corresponding xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="mango.matts.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_login_gradient">

    <include layout="@layout/anchors"/>

    <!--Start login-->

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/loginContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="@dimen/material_dialog_elevation"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/login_container_padding_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/login_container_padding_vertical"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/login_container_padding_horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/login_container_padding_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/login_container_margin_bottom">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvLoginTitle"
            style="@style/MaterialTypography.Regular.Title"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/login_content_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/login_text_margin_bottom"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="@string/login"/>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/etEmail"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/login_text_margin_bottom"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/etPassword"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/login_text_margin_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            style="@style/MaterialTypography.Regular.Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_login_height" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvNotRegistered"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loginContainer"
        style="@style/MaterialTypography.Regular"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/notRegisteredSignup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!--End login-->
    <!--Start Signup-->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/signupContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="@dimen/material_dialog_elevation"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/login_container_padding_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/login_container_padding_vertical"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/login_container_padding_horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/login_container_padding_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/login_container_margin_bottom">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvSignupTitle"
            style="@style/MaterialTypography.Regular.Title"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/login_content_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/login_text_margin_bottom"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="@string/signup"/>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/etEmailSignup"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/login_text_margin_bottom"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/etPasswordSignup"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/login_text_margin_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/btnSignup"
            android:text="@string/signup"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            style="@style/MaterialTypography.Regular.Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_login_height" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvAlreadyHaveAAccount"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signupContainer"
        style="@style/MaterialTypography.Regular"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/alreadyAMemberLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

that happens because the call to `animate()` returns always the same `ViewPropertyAnimator` object. It's an internal object of that particular view.

I believe it is like that for efficiency reasons, no need to create new object on every call.

For us developers, that means that all parameters that we set on that object are kept between calls. So if you call `setDuration(1234)` and later on there's another call to animate, it will still use 1234ms as the duration. Same thing for delay, interpolator or `setListener`.

So, the way to make it work is to always reset any parameters that you're not using for that animation. Meaning you should call `.setListener(null)` to any animation that does not use listener.

You could as well create a helper method like:

```
static ViewPropertyAnimator animate(View view){
    return view.animate()
        .setListener(null)
        .setDuration(DEFAULT_DURATION)
        .setStartDelay(0)
        .setInterpolator(DEFAULT_INTERPOLATOR);
}
```