# how to isolate multiple viewpropertyanimator set into a reusable class

Tags: android, android-animation

I have two use this function in two activities, how do I fix this mess?

```
public void startPlayActivityWithTransition() {
    ViewCompat.animate(mNavigateMenu)
        .translationX(-mNavigateMenu.getWidth())
        .setDuration(150)
        .setListener(new ViewPropertyAnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(View view) {
                    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307283/why-does-running-a-second-viewpropertyanimation-on-a-view-break-the-animation-li
                    ((ImageView)mNavigateMenu).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back);
                    ViewCompat
                        .animate(view)
                        .translationX(0)
                        .setDuration(150)
                        .setListener(new ViewPropertyAnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(View view) {
                                    startPlayActivity();
                                }
                            })
                        .start();
                }
            })
        .start();
}
```